# How to remove comment link title attribute?

Tags: theme-development, themes, comments, links

When I hover over any post's comment link, I see the title: "Comment on Post Title". How can I remove it? I could not find this text in the theme.

Edit: Here's the source which generates the comments link:

```
<?php comments_popup_link( __('0', 'domain'), __( '1', 'domain'), __('%', 'domain')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `title` attribute is hard-coded in `comments_popup_link()` unfortunately:

```
echo ' title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __('Comment on %s'), $title ) ) . '">';
```

What you can do is catching the generated HTML in a variable and replacing the attribute with an empty string:

```
ob_start();
comments_popup_link();
print preg_replace( '~ title="[^"]+"~', '', ob_get_clean() );
```